# Assign Multiple Custom User Roles to a Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, user-roles

Okay here's the situation.... I'm working on a my business website. There will be a work/portfolio area. "Work" is a custom post type. "Designer" is a custom user role. "Client" is a custom user role.

In creating a new "Work" post I would like to be able to select both a "designer" and "Client" to assign to the piece of work, as I would assign an author to a regular ol' post.

I tried the method from this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25383/assign-a-custom-role-to-a-custom-post) but it did not work for me. ) I placed it in my functions.php file.

`  add_filter('wp_dropdown_users', 'test');
    function test($output) 
    {
        global $post;

```
    //Doing it only for the custom post type
    if($post->post_type == 'work')
    {
        $users = get_users(array('role'=>'designer'));
       //We're forming a new select with our values, you can add an option 
       //with value 1, and text as 'admin' if you want the admin to be listed as well, 
       //optionally you can use a simple string replace trick to insert your options, 
       //if you don't want to override the defaults
       $output .= "<select id='post_author_override' name='post_author_override' class=''>";
    foreach($users as $user)
    {
        $output .= "<option value='".$user->id."'>".$user->user_login."</option>";
    }
    $output .= "</select>";
 }
 return $output;
}
```

`

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This plugin may be what you're looking for 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/

And this tutorial might also help, if you're not looking to use a plugin:
http://shoutingwords.com/how-to-add-custom-user-roles-like-guest-author-to-your-wordpress-blog.html

Comment: I actually have been using posts 2 posts which lets you connect posts, pages and users to each other. Thanks for the suggestion.